# Can't check if document exists in cloud firestore database and with reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I was doing a simple project when I encountered a problem in the firestore database code, When I check if a document exists it only returns true but never false event when it should do

**My Code:**

```js
    db.collection("Users")
            .where("email", "==", state.email_value).get()
            .then(function(querySnapshot) {
                querySnapshot.forEach(function(doc) {
                    if(doc.exists) {
                        console.log("Document Exist");
                    } else {
                        console.log("Document Doesn't Exist);
                    }
                });
            });
```

The Code only executes when the condition is true but not false. I even tried outputing the `doc.exists` value but it only outputs when its true

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If there are no documents, the `querySnapshot.forEach(function(doc) ...` will never be entered.

You'll want to instead check if the query itself has results:

```
db.collection("Users")
        .where("email", "==", state.email_value).get()
        .then(function(querySnapshot) {
            if (!querySnapshot.empty) {
                console.log("Document Exist");
            }
            else {
                console.log("Document Doesn't Exist");
            }
        });
```

For situations like this, I highly recommend keeping the reference documentation of Firebase handy: https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.QuerySnapshot

Comment: thank you so much I've been looking all day.